# setup.py '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, setup.py

I tried to create a setup.py file to create a python package. I uploaded the project on GitHub. When I downloaded from the command prompt, using git install+https://..., and it shows this error:

```
INFO Traceback (most recent call last):
                                                                                                                                         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-smjhaxs4\setup.py", line 23, in <module>                                                                                     "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",                                                                                                            

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup                                                       return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)                                                                                                                                           

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup                                                                          dist.run_commands()                                                                                                                                                            

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands                                                                   self.run_command(cmd)                                                                                                                                                          

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command                                                                    cmd_obj.run()                                                                                                                                                                  

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 289, in run                                                 writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))                                                                                                                    

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 621, in write_pkg_info                                      metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)                                                                                                                                          

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 1117, in write_pkg_info                                                                self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)                                                                                                                                                  

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 168, in write_pkg_file                                                  long_desc = rfc822_escape(self.get_long_description())                                                                                                                         

File "c:\users\x\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\distutils\util.py", line 464, in rfc822_escape                                                                  lines = header.split('\n')                                                                                                                                                   AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'
```

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from distutils.core import Extension

with open("README.md", "r") as readme_file:
    readme = readme_file.read()

setup(
    name="py-levenshtein",
    version="1.0",
    license="GPL",
    author="x",
    author_email="grokwithahul@gmail.com",
    description="Levenshtein project for python",
    long_description=open("README.md"),
    project_urls={
        "Source": "https://github.com/Redstomite/py-levenshtein",
        "Say Thanks!": "https://saythanks.io/to/grokwithrahul%40gmail.com",
    },
    packages=find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    ],
)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `long_description` needs to look like:

```py
long_description=open("README.md").read(),
```

Since the file handle itself has no method called `split`, but the string coming from `read` does

Comment: Thank You! That seems to have taken care of the problem